# Check if running script is in array

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm trying to run a function but only on specific pages. I thought this would be fine...

```
$allowed_pages = array('/admin/update.php', '/admin/system.php', '/admin/install.php');
if($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] == $allowed_pages) {
    myCoolFuntion();
}
```

...but it doesn't seem to work as expected and the `myCoolFuntion()` runs regardless of what page I am on.

If I echo `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` on any given page, I can see it does match up correctly (it matches a page specified in the array, for example, `/admin/update.php` as expected) and so I know the values in the array are in the correct format.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the example provided, I can't see any way that `myCoolFunction();` can ever execute.

`$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` will never be equal to `$allowed_pages` because the first is a `string` and the second is an `array`.

Instead of the code as presented, use a function such as `in_array` to verify that the `SCRIPT_NAME` value is in the array:

```
$allowed_pages = array('/admin/update.php', '/admin/system.php', '/admin/install.php');
if (in_array($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], $allowed_pages)) {
    myCoolFunction();
} else {
    echo 'Not found in array';
}
```

`in_array` is defined thus:

> Checks if a value exists in an array

More information about `in_array` is in the official [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).